# Android Facebook Account Kit Crash - missing metadata: /com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/PhoneNumberMetadataProto_CN

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, libphonenumber, account-kit

I am suddenly getting a number of crash reports around this the past few weeks. The crashes indicated missing metadata for certain country code. Most of them have been one of:

- PhoneNumberMetadataProto_CN
- PhoneNumberMetadataProto_BR
- PhoneNumberMetadataProto_IR

The crashes seems to have occurred out of nowhere.  I attempted to upgrade the AccountKit version from 4.28.0 to 4.31.0.  This resulted in a moving where the crash occurred from `com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Utility.parseNumber` to `com.facebook.accountkit.ui.PhoneNumberTextWatcher.getFormattedNumber` but the crash is still occurring.

My next plan of attack is to try including the `com.googlecode.libphonenumber` dependency directly via Gradle instead of letting it just get included transitively from the AccountKit SDK, but I'm not holding my breath that it will fix the problem.  Any other ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am having same problem here.
i am endup with adding dependency in gradle (like your next plan). Its working fine.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.+'
}
```

Comment: I am using this:"com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.10", but still gets above exception while invoking PhoneNumberUtil.parse